# Greek Document in LyX - "Corrupted NFSS Tables"

Tags: lyx, greek

I am trying to write a document in Greek using LyX but I get the 5 "Corrupted NFSS tables".

I installed every font package I found and every package related to the greek language. What can I do to fix that?

The log is [this](https://pastebin.com/87N5UVw4).

Comment: Could we have a minimal code reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard What do you mean code? I opened LyX and I just wrote a single greek word. Nothing else.

Comment: Behind the scene, there's LaTeX code, describing the document class, the fonts loaded, &c, in a preamble, then the body of the document.

Comment: @Bernard Oh how do I find this code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have LyX installed, but I'm pretty sure you can get it through a menu.

Comment: @Bernard I will find it and add it here.

Comment: There should be File->Export->LaTeX (pdflatex) or something like that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it uses xelatex to compile so it shouldn't load lgr at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer arg I skipped down to the error didn't notice it was xetex, I'll delete the comment thanks